# SQL Server - Handling Parent/Child Relationships (Ordering/Grouping)

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, parent-child, grouping

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I'd like to generate a list of help desk tickets, with their respective child tickets (if exists) listed directly below them. This will ultimately be an SSRS report, but I just don't know if the logic is best handled in the SQL query or in SSRS (grouping/sorts/etc).

Our Help Desk system allows for tickets to be designated as child tickets of a parent ticket (i.e., a ticket is generated by a user, and the tech then creates a related new ticket (child ticket) for some back-end work from our network guys). I'm working on a SSRS report that lists all open tickets over 60 days old. I'd like any child tickets to be located directly beneath the parent ticket and sorted by date created.

The report is grouped, initially, by location. Each ticket record, whether the ticket is a child or parent, will display the same data (Ticket No, Ticket Subject, Contact, Date Started, Status, etc.), and all tickets will have a unique ticket number. So, this is largely a grouping/sorting issue. Ideally, once in SSRS, I'll be able to format the group heirarchy, so that child tickets are visually distinct in some way (indented, borders/lines/etc.)

I just can't wrap my head around the logic. I can provide code if it helps, so you can see the existing query, but I primarily just need an idea of which direction to go.

EDIT: I should add that all tickets have a PARENTID field, which is NULL if the ticket is not the child of another ticket.

2ND EDIT: Read up on CTE recursion, felt good about it, then was reminded that I'm working with SQL Server 2000. I might have to get creative. Maybe this will be the motivation required to upgrade to 2008R2. Any ideas for this type of recursion on a turn of the millennium database management system?

Thank you,

Robert

Comment: A Recursive CTE is the way to do this. You can find zillions of examples around here and every other corner of the internet. :)

Comment: Sean mean something like [THIS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)